# How to validate associated objects numbers while updating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, strong-parameters

Can't understand how to validate associatiated models size while updating main model. In my app product can't have more than 6 attached images. Every image I store in class ProductAttachment

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :product_attachments, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_attachments
validate :validate_attachments_count


  def validate_attachments_count
    if self.product_attachments.size > 6
      errors.add(:product_attachments, 'Pic number should not be more than 6')
    end
  end
end
```

**product_attachment.rb**

```
class ProductAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
belongs_to :product
after_destroy :delete_picture

private
  def delete_picture
    self.remove_picture!
  end
end
```

and in products_controller I've got a create method

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(products_params)
  # if pics available add attachments
  if params[:product_attachments] != nil
    params[:product_attachments]['picture'].each do |p|
      @product_attachment = @product.product_attachments.build(:picture => p)
    end
  end
  if @product.save
      flash[:success] = 'Product created.'
      redirect_to [current_user, @product]
  else
      flash[:danger] = 'Product not created'
      render 'new'
  end
end
```

which works fine and creation rejected if I try to attach more than 6 pictures, but update method can't determine number of atachments somehow and allow to add any numbers of pictures

```
def update
  if @product.update_attributes(products_params)
    if params[:product_attachments] != nil
      params[:product_attachments]['picture'].each do |p|
        @product_attachment = @product.product_attachments.create(:picture => p)
      end
    end
    flash[:success] = 'Info updated.'
    redirect_to [current_user, @product]
  else
    flash[:danger] = 'Can't update'
    render :edit
  end
end
```

I guess I should change somemething in products_params method but I can't figured out what exactly

```
def products_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :width, :height, :depth, :color, :price, :category, :description,
  product_attachments_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :picture, :remove_picture])
end
```

this is a form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <% if @product.new_record? %>
      <%= f.fields_for :product_attachments do |p| %>
        <div class="control-label col-md-4">
          <%= p.label :picture, 'Pictures' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= p.file_field :picture, multiple: true, name: 'product_attachments[picture][]' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <div class="control-label col-md-4"><strong>Pictures</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <% @product.product_attachments.each do |p| %>
            <%= image_tag p.picture_url, class: 'pic' %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', product_attachment_path(p),
                        method: :delete , data: { confirm: 'Sure?'} %>
          <% end %>
          <%= f.fields_for :product_attachments, @product.product_attachments.new do |p| %>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <%= p.file_field :picture, multiple: true, name: 'product_attachments[picture][]' %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manually trigger that validation by adding an explicitly @product.save call inside the happy path of #update.